# No cambia el color del boton a pesar que le puse background - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, background

Hola tengo un boton que debería cambiar a color verde pero sigue en color morado a pesar que le puse background android:background="@drawable/select_btn_primary"

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnConsultar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buscar"
                android:background="@drawable/select_btn_primary"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/noto_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Consultar"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
```

El codigo esta aquí https://github.com/Miguel546/datetimepicker/blob/main/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml de la línea 68 a la línea 80.

¿Por qué no cambia de color si le puesto la propiedad background?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el select_btn_primary.xml
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les paso el código fuente.

https://github.com/Miguel546/datetimepicker

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: estas usando algún complemento como `material design` de `google`? porque usan el `colorPrimary` para ese violeta que estas mostrando y para un verde seria `success` no se si te sirva pero te lo dejo por las dudas.

Comment: En el select_btn_primary.xml ahí le pongo todos los colores para el background y ese background lo pongo al boton pero no cambia de color, background.

Answer (score 1):

Debas ingresar a(Res, Values, Themes) y en ambos themes.xml el la línea donde comienza el  Style  modificas solo la parte  parent. debe quedar de la siguiente manera

```
<style name="Theme.ButtonChanger" 
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Sin embargo si no te funciona, te dejo un tutorial (https://youtu.be/AdlxIdYus14) que te servirá. solo sigue las instrucciones.

Comment: Gracias me funcionó sabes porque no funciona con Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar?

Comment: Con los temas DayNight se seleccionará automáticamente como tema base de la app un tema de Material Components de tipo Light o Dark según ordene Android, es decir que es un tema predeterminado.

Comment: Esta no es una respuesta aceptable, le indicas que cambie todo su theme por otro, lo cual no es correcto ya que si está usando MaterialComponents, debe de exsitir alguna alternativa, no cambiar todo el estilo.